# Swift - How to find Largest value from an array and identify which array it came from

Tags: arrays, swift

```
    var amya = (1)
    var amyb = (2)
    var amyc = (3)
    var amyd = (3)
    var amye = (9)
    var amyf = (3)
    var amyg = (4)
    var amyh = (4)
    var amyi = (10)
    var amyj = (1)
```

> ///Create array with all values

```
  let users1 = [amya,amyb,amyc,amyd,amye,amyf,amyg,amyh,amyi,amyj]
```

> ////Find the max number

```
 let maxnum = maxElement(users1)
```

> ////Result is 10

My question is how to find which variable the result "10" came from without doing a massive amount of if statements.

I want result to be "amyi"

Comment: Just loop through the elements in users1 until you find the value of 10

Comment: How about a loop? lol - 8 seconds too late

Answer (score 2):

Actually I think the issue is for return the variable name instead of the value. You can achieve it by Swift dictionary. Sample code is like:

```
let users1 = [
"amya": 1,
"amyb": 2,
"amyc": 10
]
let max = users1.values.maxElement()

func allKeysForValue<K, V : Equatable>(dict: [K : V], val: V) -> [K] {
    return dict.filter{ $0.1 == val }.map{ $0.0 }
}

let keys = allKeysForValue(users1, val: max!)
print(keys)
```

The result is: `"[amyc]"`

It will find which variable the result largest value came from and return the variable names as keys.

Answer (score -1):

There is a much easier way to do that than the answer above. If you have all your values in an array and you would like to find the largest, simply do the following:

```
let array = [1,10,6,3,5,9,7]
let sortedArray = array.sorted()
let largestElement = sortedArray.last
```

The above code will sort the array and then the last element will always be the largest. This should work on Swift 5. I don't know about previous versions of Swift.