# Swift - How to find max or min element in Dictionary and Two-dimensional Array in Array list

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I am trying to find out what to write the code for this specific two examples in Swift for finding max or min element in Dictionary with Array and Two-dimensional Array in Array list.

**Example #1 - Find max element in Two-dimensional Array**

```
let myArray = [["A_1", "1"], ["A_2", "0"], ["A_3", "25"], ["A_4", "3"]]
print(myArray.maxElement()!) // <--- it doesn't work properly

Output: 25
```

**Example #2 - Which key has (highest items count) max element in Dictionary with Array**

```
let myList = [("A_1", [["C", "C"]]), ("A_2", [["A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["C", "C"]]), ("A_3", [])]

.... //Trying to figure it out what kind of code to add here... 


Output: A_2  //has 3 items in array
```

Comment: use custom method to count maximum or minium from dictionary , for finding max , min of numeric value possible not with string

Comment: What are your expected outputs for the 2 examples?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Have you seen outputs above? That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Your first example is an array of 2-arrays. `1`, `0`, `25` etc. are strings, not numbers. And I can make any sense out of your second example

Comment: @CodeDifferent right I can convert `1`, `0`, `25` to numbers from string. First example I am trying to figure out how to get max element from these `1`, `0`, `25`. For some reasons, `print(myArray.maxElement()!)` doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of way to write this, here's one:

```
let myArray = [["A_1", 1], ["A_2", 0], ["A_3", 25], ["A_4", 3]]
let result1 = myArray.reduce(myArray.first!) { aggregate, element in
    if let aggregateValue = aggregate[1] as? Int,
        let elementValue = element[1] as? Int where aggregateValue < elementValue {
        return element
    } else {
        return aggregate
    }
}[1]

let myList = [("A_1", [["C", "C"]]), ("A_2", [["A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["C", "C"]]), ("A_3", [])]
let result2 = myList.reduce(myList.first!) { aggregate, element in
    aggregate.1.count < element.1.count ? element : aggregate
}.0

print(result1)
print(result2)
```

Basically `reduce` starts with a seed value (the first element of each array), then iterate through the array to determine which is the max overall.

Comment: Wow, it made so much sense. I didn't think about this part. I always looking for simplest part. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good example for your Example #1. Maybe you can change things to a better one. But what @CodeDifferent provided is a really good example also. You can see this example what I found:

[Swift - How to find Largest value from an array and identify which array it came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245141/swift-how-to-find-largest-value-from-an-array-and-identify-which-array-it-came)

I thought you would like to see it.